# What to do when a user wants SO to teach him how to code?

Tags: discussion

3 hours ago, an user posted this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903828/how-to-compute-area-of-a-superpixel and just now, he posted this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907039/how-to-compute-shape-features-of-a-superpixel.

Both lack of search effort, Almost same text, same picture... What could we do with this kind of issue?

Comment: Downvote both questions. Looks like the most recent one could possibly be closed as a duplicate of the older one. Then close the older one possibly for being too broad.

Comment: The first thing to do when a user self-duplicates is to close the duplicate. Usually this means closing the newer question. In some *rare* cases I've voted to close the older one. This has happened, for instance, when the duplicate got an excellent answer. I decided that promoting the visibility of the excellent answer was the overriding consideration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Downvote, closevote and / or comment.

SO is not a tutorial site.

These example questions show a significant lack of effort, they're pure code requests.

Comment: I get annoyed when I know a simple search will find their answer, or their question just shows no research effort at all! New academic year time!

Comment: @user3791372 - You'd figure that with the high search rankings given to SO, students would realize that answers they get are easily found by their teachers/professors. At least if they went to ExpertSexChange their answer would never be found. :) (Yes I know they hyphenated their name, but I refuse to do it.)

Comment: @theB you're forgetting that lots of lecturers are as lazy as their students!

Comment: And a lot aren't.